# java three conditions for Memory Game

Tags: java

I am trying to make a memory card game with 3 conditions:

1. when the player start the game the first click reveal the first card
2. if the player click in the second card there are 2 options
    
    a. the second card have the same value as the first card. Hence keep both of them.
    b. the second card have different value. Hence flip both back when click

[image]

I don't know what is the best way to deal with this problem. I thought of using if statement and making new method "state" which should have 3 outputs.

```
public void mousePressed() {
    if(state==READY){
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
             if(mouseX >= cards[i].x && 
                mouseX <= cards[i].x+cards[i].WIDTH && 
                mouseY >= cards[i].y && 
                mouseY <= cards[i].y+cards[i].HEIGHT) {
                   cards[i].flip();
              }
        }
    }            
    else if (state==FIRST_CHOSEN){

    }        
    else{

    }        
}
```

Comment: You need to keep the card chosen first.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @matheszabi The OP has posted 3 question relating to the same game, but they do appear to be distinct. I wouldn't describe it as low quality, as plenty of information *is* included. I think it's just that OP does not know the best questions to ask, and that this site may not be the best format for them. We don't need to discourage/confuse beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break the problem into smaller problems.

Have several different methods that solve a little task that is required to tackle the larger end goal:

- public void revealCard(Card card)
- public boolean isMatch(Card card)
- public void flipCardsBackOver(Card card1, Card card2);

And add an instance variable that stores the card that is already up. Once you have broken apart all of the separate challenges, then your problem becomes an easy one:

```
private Card CardOne; //instance variable

public void revealCard(Card myCard) {
  myCard.flipCard(); //Whatever task you need to flip the card
  if (CardOne = null) {
     myCard = CardOne;
     return;
  }
  if myCard.isMatch(CardOne)) {
      //Do whatever you need to do when there is a match
  }
  else {
  this.flipCardsBackOver(myCard, CardOne) //Flip all up cards over and set Card1
        //to null
  }
}
```